# Django custom template tag sort long list of 'elif'

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I have a Django custom template tag that changes the color of a font depending on the value that is put in.

Everything works fine but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of writing this instead of making all these `elif` statements. Shown isn't even half of the teams, there are still 3 other leagues of teams that would be included in that tag.

```py
@register.filter(name='teamColor')
def teamColor(team):

    if team == "Celtics" or team == "Jazz":
        return "green"
    elif (team == "Hawks" or team == "Bulls" or team == "Rockets"
          or team == "Pistons" or team == "Clippers" or team == "Heat" or
          team == "Trail Blazers" or team == "Raptors"):
        return "red"
    elif team == "Nets":
        return "grey"
    elif (team == "Hornets" or team == "Lakers" or team == "Suns" or
          team == "Kings"):
        return "purple"
    elif team == "Cavaliers":
        return "#b11226"
    elif team == "Mavericks" or team == "Grizzlies" or team == "76ers":
        return "blue"
    elif team == "Nuggets" or team == "Pacers":
        return "yellow"
    elif (team == "Warriors" or team == "Timberwolves" or team == "Thunder" or
          team == "Knicks"):
        return "#1D428A"
    elif team == "Bucks":
        return "#00471b"
    elif team == "Pelicans":
        return "gold"
    elif team == "Magic":
        return "#0077C0"
    elif team == "Spurs" or team == "Wizards":
        return "silver"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put everything in a dictionary (look-up table).

```
@register.filter(name='team_color')
def team_color(team):
    team_colors = {
        'Celtics':  'green',
        'Jazz':     'green',
        'Hawks':    'red',
        'Bulls':    'red',
        'Rockets':  'red',
        'Pistons':  'red',
        'Clippers': 'red',
        'Heat':     'red',
        # ... etc ..
    }
    return team_colors[team]
```

This is both really fast and clear. And you can also use `return team_colors.get(team, default='no_color')` instead to return a default color if the team doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, a better approach is to keep these data in a `.py` file like a module and import it to the views. [Better to keep those data in a "settings" file.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings).

Comment: @Alireza Maybe. It depends on their use-case and whether the problem is prone to change. Having the dictionary encapsulated and inlined into the function is the fastest, cleanest and the least amount of complexity there can be. But it isn't very dynamic and could be hard for someone outside (say a designer) to find and change. However, when/if that requirement comes, it's very easy to refactor it out to a settings file when needed.

Comment: That's it. I personally use my suggested method in pure-python projects. Mostly use it for loading a config file or something like that. But Django can handle those `.py` files very well. Thanks for the answer. <3

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to list your all teams with their desired colors in a `.json` file, import it to your views, and try to catch the color with the following method.

```py
import json

def getTeamColor(team):
   with open('file.json') as file:   # file contains teams and colors
       team_colors = json.load(file)
   
   for teams in tuple(team_colors.keys()):
       if team in teams:
           return team_colors[teams]
```

And the JSON file should be like the following structure.

```json
{
    "('Celtics', 'Jazz')": "green",
    "('Hawks', 'Bulls', 'Rockets')": "red",
    "('Nets',)": "grey",
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against this. Loading from disk for every request is going to be really slow and introduce much more complexity than needed. You're also doing a `O(n)` search for the team when you could be doing a `O(1)` lookup instead.

Comment: Well, the amount of data is fixed somehow. (NBA never introduces a team that quick)
But I totally agree with that. Working with the variables is much better in Django.